# Car blinker setup, turning off parking lights when blinker signal is high

Tags: mosfet, automotive

I have a basic idea of how to do this, but I could use some help. Not sure what transistors to buy. LED is less than 5 watts. Voltage may fluctuate 12v-14v. I came up with this circuit. Input from blinker relay should cause the second mosfet to be pulled to ground. Is N-channel a proper choice?

[image]

Comment: So you want the parking light to blink off every time the turn signal blinks on? Typical "switchback" setups on modern cars keep the parking lights off until the turn signal is disengaged.

Comment: @kjgregory This car is from 1990, the parking lights currently just stay on. I want to increase visibility, the front turn signal is not visible from a side angle. https://i.imgur.com/6l1YVJs.jpg

Comment: have you found a node that has constant (not pulsing) +12V when the blinkers are engaged  (i mean 12 to 14v like you normally see in a car)   because if noy you may be making an illusion that the wrong turn signal is on.

Comment: why not just use a relay?

Comment: @Jasen Relays are slightly slower and have a shorter lifespan, while costing close to the same amount. There is a constant 12v but that would require running a wire from under the dash rather than tapping into the wire in the engine bay.

Comment: I have installed a lot of car alarms in my youth, and relays were the de-facto way to interface incompatible circuits. As pointed out in the above comments, you need to find the non-blinking wire that triggers this action. Use a DVM. Learn something, and be glad its an old car.

Answer (score 1):

From your schematic, it looks like you are trying to construct a basic inverter. I would suggest something like this instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCbBbc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The portion within the red box is a typical CMOS inverter. I wouldn't recommend using the 3 MΩ resistor pull-up shown in your schematic.

The input to the inverter is your blinker signal. Here I'm using an SPDT switch to highlight the fact that you must be sure that the relay switches between a high level (+12V) and *ground* (or a pull-down to ground). In other words, make sure that your relay isn't floating when the relay is not active.

The output of the inverter then goes to a driver for your LED. The Zener acts as a simple regulator to protect against voltage spikes.

You'll have to play with R<sub>1</sub> to satisfy the requirements of your LED (light).

Comment: Seems like a 1N4733 (5V1) model is automatically selected by the schematic editor when you placed a zener. Please correct it because it simply ruins all the operation of the circuit. Actually, since **the specs of the LED are not given** and the LED is placed as an emitter load, placing a zener there is not a good idea even if the purpose is protection. Seems like you're assuming that it is a single LED or paralleled single LEDs but what if it is a 12V module or a COB? By the way, 10k is way too high for biasing a zener since zeners need at least 5mA for proper operation.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I didn’t assume anything. I could only go by the schematic provided by the OP. I simulated the circuit and it seems to work great. Although, I agree that the 10k should probably be more like 2k.

Comment: @BlairFornville The circuit works great if the forward voltage of the LED is 2 to 5V (or something like that), but it is not given that the LED is a single chip. The only spec given is the power. I'm asking again: What if it is a 12V module? Please set the forward voltage of the LED to 12V in your simulator and see if it works.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I can’t edit the schematic from my phone, to change the resistor value. I’ll have to do so tomorrow. I think the rest is fine. The Zener provides fair protection, and protection is certainly needed here.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Our messages crossed. To your last comment: fair enough- I do have to assume that the forward voltage of the LED is low enough - but it’s not given by the OP.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand, I'm not judging you. There's no problem with the protection idea, and I agree with you about it. But in your circuit, the LED is an emitter load. And the base voltage of the transistor will be set by the zener when 12V comes from the CMOS inverter. So, \$V_{Zener} = V_{BE} + I_{Load} \cdot R3 + V_F\$. If \$V_F\$ is low enough then yes, the circuit works great. But if it's 12V then the LED will not light up. I would remove R3, put an NMOS instead of an NPN-BJT and put the LED to the high side instead of low side.

Comment: @RohatKılıç No worries. I didn’t misjudged, and I always appreciate feedback. I agree with your suggestion, and almost did just that. In hindsight I should have. I’ll incorporate your modifications tomorrow (unless you would care to make the edits now). Thanks.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I went ahead and fired the computer back up. Schematic edited per your comments.

Comment: you're going to want a fuse for when the mosfet gate fails in a load dump.

Comment: @Jasen Presumably the blinker input will be low during crank - so M1 and M2 should be fine. M3 is protected by the Zener. Still... can’t hurt.

Comment: i'm seeign guidelines to design to withstand 100V, load might not be cranking, could be a shorted headlamp....

Comment: @Jasen probably already a fuse for that under the dashboard. While I doubt that current would somehow feed into the blinker signal, as I said, it can’t hurt to add a fuse - so I don’t disagree.

Comment: 40v and M1 or M2 is going to fail.

Comment: @Jasen other than saying that I agree with you that a front end fuse would be a fine thing to do, I don’t know what to say. Stop listing voltages that would be bad to have.